# How to replace tabs in a string?

Tags: python

I need to replace tabs in a string, *but only the tabs*, not the spaces.

If I use the str.replace() function, what would go in the first set of quotes?

Comment: replace the tab with four space? `user_input.replace('\t', '    ')`

Comment: @amow StackOverflow's formatting swallowed your spaces.

Comment: google first, please.

Answer (score 19):

In python string literals, the '\t' pair represents the tab character.  So you would use `mystring.replace('\t', 'any other string that you want to replace the tab with')`.

Comment: @VivekDani If it does not work for you, you should check your python installation.  `str` is a built in type, and `replace` has been a method on strings ever since strings had methods.

Comment: @VivekDani make sure that you do: `mystr = mystr.replace('\t', 'whatever')`, just calling replace on the string won't alter it but instead return a new string.

Answer (score 13):

```
str.replace("\t", "TAB_WAS_HERE")
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with an explanation to the asker that "\t" is an escape sequence that means a tab in python string literals (and a number of other languages).

Answer (score 0):

This is too late for original poster, but for those that follow ...

```
def expandTab( txt, tabWidth=8):
out=[]
for line in txt.split('\n'):
    try:
        while True:
            i = line.index( '\t')
            if ( tabWidth > 0 ):
                pad = " " * (tabWidth - (i % tabWidth))
            else :
                pad = ""
            line = line.replace("\t", pad, 1)
    except:
        out.append(line)
return "\n".join(out)
```